# ERROR CON CRUD EN PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este error en un crud que estoy realizando. No sé la respuesta, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?.

Error fatal:

```
PDOException no detectada: SQLSTATE [HY093]: Número de parámetro no válido: parámetros con nombre y posición mezclados en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ CrediValores Formulario \ model \ modelo \ DAO.php: 26 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ CrediValores Formulario \ model \ modelo \ DAO.php (26): PDOStatement-> execute () # 1 C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ CrediValores Formulario \ model \ modelo \ Controlador.php (20): Crud-> insertar (Object ( Usuario)) # 2 {main} arrojado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ CrediValores Formulario \ model \ modelo \ DAO.php en la línea 26
```

Codigo

```
public function insertar($Usuarios)
    {
    $con = Conexion::Conexion($Usuarios);
    $usuarios = new Usuario();
    $insert = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios( :Nombre, :Apellido, :Cedula, :Correo, :Celular, :confirmarNun, :Ciudad, :Ocupacion, :Entidad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    
    $insert->bindValue('nombre',$Usuarios->getNombre());
    $insert->bindValue('apellido',$Usuarios->getApellido());
    $insert->bindValue('cedula',$Usuarios->getCedula());
    $insert->bindValue('correo',$Usuarios->getCorreo());
    $insert->bindValue('celular',$Usuarios->getCelular());
    $insert->bindValue('connum',$Usuarios->getConfirmacion());
    $insert->bindValue('ciudad',$Usuarios->getCiudad());
    $insert->bindValue('ocupacion',$Usuarios->getOcupacion());
    $insert->bindValue('entidad',$Usuarios->getEntidad());
    $insert->execute();
}
```

Comment: Por qué le pusiste sintaxis de marcadores de parámetro a los nombres de las columnas?, cuando estos van pero en los valores que pones entre paréntesis en `VALUES`

Answer (score 2):

PDO te permite pasar<sup>1</sup>:

- Marcadores de parámetro con nombre (yo los conozco marcadores de nombre)

  ```
  :valor
  ```
- Marcadores de parámetro mediante signo de interrogación (yo los conozco como marcadores de posición)

  ```
  ?
  ```

En cualquiera de los 2 casos estos se estarían ocupando en tu escenario en la sección de `VALUES` de esta forma:

Opción 1.

```
VALUES(:marcado1, :marcador2, :marcador3)
```

Opción 2.

```
VALUES(?, ?, ?)
```

Si tomamos la primera opción entonces debería quedar así tu prepare:

```
$insert = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Correo, Celular, confirmarNun, Ciudad, Ocupacion, Entidad) 
    VALUES (:Nombre, :Apellido, :Cedula, :Correo, :Celular, :confirmarNun, :Ciudad, :Ocupacion, :Entidad)');
```

Y en consecuencia tus métodos `bindValue` deberán quedar con una estructura mas o menos así<sup>2</sup>:

```
$insert->bindValue(':parametro1', $valor1, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro2', $valor2, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro3', $valor3, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro4', $valor4, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro5', $valor5, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro6', $valor6, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro7', $valor7, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametro8', $valor8, data_type);
$insert->bindValue(':parametroN', $valorN, data_type);
$insert->execute();
```

Donde:

- `:parametro1....N`: Son los marcadores de parámetro con nombre
- `$valor1....N`: Corresponde al valor que será vinculado con el parámetro con nombre
- `data_type` deberá ser sustituido por alguna de las *constantes predefinidas* que se corresponda con el tipo de dato para el parámetro<sup>3</sup>

**Edición**

Estoy infiriendo los tipos de datos de cada parámetro (*pero si no encajan solo debes modificarlos siguiendo el enlace que te he provisto*), puedes probar tu código de esta forma:

```
$con = Conexion::Conexion($Usuarios);
$usuarios = new Usuario();
$insert = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Correo, Celular, confirmarNun, Ciudad, Ocupacion, Entidad) 
    VALUES (:Nombre, :Apellido, :Cedula, :Correo, :Celular, :confirmarNun, :Ciudad, :Ocupacion, :Entidad)');

$insert->bindValue(':Nombre', $Usuarios->getNombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Apellido', $Usuarios->getApellido(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Cedula', $Usuarios->getCedula(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Correo', $Usuarios->getCorreo(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Celular', $Usuarios->getCelular(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':confirmarNun', $Usuarios->getConfirmacion(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Ciudad', $Usuarios->getCiudad(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Ocupacion', $Usuarios->getOcupacion(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':Entidad', $Usuarios->getEntidad(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->execute();
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Marcadores en PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-description)
- <sup>2</sup> [Parámetros de `bindValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindvalue-parameters)
- <sup>3</sup> [Constantes predefinidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: Buena respuesta, como siempre, pero, ya que estamos, en vez de `:parametro1, :parametro2...` en los `bindValue()`, habría sido más claro para OP que pusieras cada parámetro por su nombre, dado que de hecho los tienes ya en la consulta. Creo que es la duda principal y así quedaría mucho más claro.

Comment: Gracias por la observación @A.Cedano, sigo tu comentario, editaré dejando la estructura de ejemplo y anexo agregaré el como debería verse con su código